# Как сделать вызов функции из разных областей видимости. Два вызова $(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такой код который выдает ошибку

```js
// Подключение в первом файле
$(function(){
  function one(){
    console.log('one');
  }
  // другой код...
});
// Подключение во втором файле
$(function(){
  one();
  // другой код...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вообщем нужно обратиться к функции из другой обрасти видимости.

Причину ошибки я понял, но в проекте изменить подключения скриптов нет возможности. Поэтому хотелось бы как то найти обходные пути.

Самое главное мне нужно обращаться из одного файла `js` к функциям другого файла `js`, или возможно `$(function(){` заменить нужно на что то другое, но обойтись совсем без него не получится, так как нужна обработка `DOM` дерева после его всей загрузки.

Сразу извиняюсь если что то не понятно, в первые столкнулся с такой проблемой и ответа не получилось ни где найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  window.one = function (){
    console.log('one');
  }
});

$(function(){
  one();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Как вариант можно записать функцию в глобальный объект `window`

Comment: Тоесть глобальный объект `window` делает такую функцию вообще доступной в любом месте?

Comment: да, window доступен везде

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/global-object вот вам стаття о глобальом объекте

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное этот вариант больше подходит, не хотелось бы совсем обходиться без `$(function(){`,так как там много всякого кода

Comment: @bolatol377 В соседнем примере `$(main)` — это и есть `$(function()`  )) Вместо анонимной функции - передано её имя.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да так и есть. Но я акцентировал внимание на другом, в вашем примере переменная записывается в объект `jQuery` а в моем в глобальный `window`. В вашем случае переменную можно использовать только внутри анонимной функции `jquery` а в моем случае в любом месте. Хорошо это или плохо зависит от ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще без изменения кода - обходных путей нет. Но в JS можно работать с функциями как с обычными объектами - добавляя им свойства через "точку".

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(main);
  
  function main() {
    function one() {
      console.log('one');
    };

    main.one = one;
  }
</script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    main.one();
  });
</script>
```